# What is the difference between flap load relief protection and overspeed protection?

Tags: boeing, boeing-767

What is the difference between flap load relief protection and overspeed protection?

Answer (score 2):

[According to this document/study guide](http://www.convectivedigital.com/guide/757-767%20Study%20Guide.pdf)

> Flap Load Relief – on the 757 and a few 767s, if the flaps are at 30
>   and Flaps 30 speed is exceeded, the flaps automatically retract to 25.
>   On most 767s, if the flaps are at 25 or 30 and the placard airspeed is
>   exceeded, the flaps automatically retract to 20. The flaps will
>   automatically re-extend when airspeed is reduced. If the Flap Load
>   Relief fails to operate when it should, the Trailing Edge light will
>   illuminate and the FLAP LD RELIEF EICAS message will display

So flap load relief is a system that specifically protects the flaps. This is the result of accelerating to higher speeds.

Overspeed is a more general term and the actual speed that defines overspeed may vary with configuration, the 767/757 has a warning for that

> Overspeed Warning – Master Warning, EICAS message, discrete light and
>   siren when airspeed exceeds Vmo/Mmo.

[It appears that overspeed protection is a function of the auto throttles](https://books.google.com/books?id=TfRcDpWw9i0C&pg=PA349&lpg=PA349&dq=767%20Overspeed%20protection&source=bl&ots=czbuveaIZZ&sig=ACfU3U3Dq6qqtwzmpOspD5wboTsAN7yNEA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiVq-WNrqHhAhXp1FkKHXajDNA4ChDoATABegQICBAB#v=onepage&q=767%20Overspeed%20protection&f=false).